# How do I extract a full html-code via beautifulsoup from a website with a refreshing feed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, feed

I want to build a corpus with posts from the 9gag feed (and later, other imageboards). For this I tried to extract the source html code. Unfortunately as soon as I want to find the articles from the feed in that html-code, it seems like the articles have not been extracted together with the html code. Using .find() always returns -None- when I search for something in the feed.

I used lxml, html.parser and html5lib at this point:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5lib')
```

I searched for a variety of keywords which showed up in the code my browser showed me, at this point:

```
entry = soup.find('div')
```

Comparing the code in my browser-inspector and in the soup-variable I get different results. The inspector finds keywords the soup variable does not find.

I tried to change the output from the `requests.get` function from `.text` to `.content` but still the needed code doesn't appear

```
##get source text of 9gag
source = requests.get('https://9gag.com').text

##make source a soup-type
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5lib')

##clip out the needed code of html for entrys
entry = soup.find('div id')
```

How can I reach the full code of the 9gag feed respectively the code that forms the separate posts?

What else might have gone wrong?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the titles of the posts?

Comment: No I need the images, titles, number of comments, date of upload and number of upvotes and later want to sort them into xml - so that for every image I can check the title and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that that the data is received in as a JSON so it would be better using just the `requests` and `JSON` library for this task. so your code should look something like this:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://9gag.com"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

json_raw = req[req.index("{\"page\":"):req.index("}})")+2]

posts = json.loads(json_raw)["data"]['posts']
```

Hope this helps